# How I can make jQuery animation like this?

Tags: jquery

I want make clouds like this [page](http://devthought.com/)

it should display in random places in header and move by random method
who I can. I used settimeout function but it's not working good

Comment: Any JavaScript animation tutorial should get you started. What is the actual problem you have?

Comment: Whats the issue with settimeout? slow?

Answer (score 4):

Use setInterval (sorry I was wrong assuming delay() could help)

Try something like this ([example here](http://jsbin.com/ozoha3/edit)). Assuming your cloud is a div:

```
    function moveMe(){
    var $this = $('#cloud');
    $this.each(function(){
           var ranX=Math.floor(Math.random()*11);
           var startX = $this.offset().left;
           var maxX = $this.parent().width(); 
           var newX = startX+ranX;

           //newX = (newX>maxX)? 0: newX;
           //alert("newX="+newX);
           $this.animate({
              left: newX+'px'

           }, "slow");
    });
}
$(function(){



   setInterval('moveMe()',1000);
});
```

Note that hte markup should contain :

```
<div id="sky">
<div class="cloud" id="cloud"></div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
#sky{
width:990px;
height:300px;
background:blue;
position:relative; /* important  */
}

.cloud{
position:absolute;  /* important  */
top:40px;
left: 0;
width:100px;
height:80px;
background: transparent url(images/cloud.png) top left no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: With all due respect, if you aren't going to be offering even a *little* direction, you shouldn't post this as an "answer." (Note: I didn't downvote you, as I agree with your statement, just not its location.)

Comment: point taken. I've updated with my solution.

Answer (score 2):

The clouds appear to be draggable within their container. When you mouse over, another element is animated, and the clouds themselves slide side to side in their parent container when you hover the parent.

1. [jQuery's draggable plugin](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/).
2. [`$.hover();`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) for animated rain.
3. [`$.animate();`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) for the sliding.

Show us what you've tried and you'll get a more detailed response.

Comment: iam dont want ir rian or hover just i want it moving

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how in jQuery, but in simple JS, its an image moving with a Timer. On Firefox and using FireBug you can see the code in the clouds